# How to access backend after deploying website on Heroku?

Tags: reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

My backend runs on port 5000 on localhost. So obviously when I connect to the backend from the frontend using `const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000')` others around the world will not be able to access it. I've deployed the React App on Heroku.

[https://murmuring-reaches-27066.herokuapp.com/]

Copy ID button isn't working because I don't understand how to connect to the backend when it's on production mode.
My Backend code (Only included relevant code)

```
const express = require("express")
const http = require("http")
const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "https://murmuring-reaches-27066.herokuapp.com/",
        methods: [ "GET", "POST" ]
    }
})
```

Any help is appreciated.